# IOS8 - AutoLayout Size Class Change Notification/Delegate

Tags: ios, storyboard, ios8

In my application I have a view that is different sizes in portrait and landscape.  I need to have the backend controller code trigger a "redraw" of some graphical elements in this view when the phone changes. How do I do this?  Is there some sort of delegate call to the `UIView` to know when its size has changed?

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-nsnotification--mobile-10619

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is implement following method in your custom controller:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    //do sth when rotated
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also write a custom like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    //Redraw Here
}
```

Comment: Updating the answer: In modern iOS `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` wouldn't always called when width of the screen changes: for example if the app goes to side-by-side mode on iPad.